# How to convert SQL query in laravel query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-5

I know this question is not asked in a well manner way,so I am sorry,I have SQL query this one

```
`SELECT
    c.*
FROM
    merchantlink m,
    company c,
    merchantlinkrelation mlr
WHERE
    (m.initiator_user_id = c.owner_user_id AND
     m.responder_user_id = 86 AND
     mlr.ptype='dealer')
     OR
    (m.initiator_user_id = 86 AND
     m.responder_user_id = c.owner_user_id AND
     mlr.ptype = 'dealer')
     OR
    (m.initiator_user_id = c.owner_user_id AND
     c.owner_user_id=86 AND
     mlr.ptype='dealer')
GROUP BY
    c.id;`
```

I want to convert it in PHP laravel query form so tried this query

```
 $twowaycompany = DB::table('company')
                ->join('merchantlink','merchantlink.responder_user_id', 'company.owner_user_id')
->join('merchantlinkrelation','merchantlinkrelation.merchantlink_id','merchantlink.id')
                
                ->orWhere('merchantlink.initiator_user_id', 86)
                ->join('merchantlink','merchantlink.initiator_user_id', 'company.owner_user_id')
                ->orWhere('merchantlink.responder_user_id', 86)
                ->pluck('name')->toArray();
```

but I don't know SQL and even I am not understanding how I convert it, can someone help just convert SQL query to laravel query?

here is the db image merchante link [image]

merchantlinkrelation
[image]

[image]

Comment: Check: https://jjlabajo.github.io/SQLtoEloquent/ and I suggest you use proper join in your `MySQL` query

Comment: And you do not have a join condition for `merchantlinkrelation` table

Comment: can you please add a photo of the DB schema? So that I can help you to write the query.

Comment: ok i add the db imagees

Comment: @KudosIntech i have added images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please I have tried to create a query (Laravel Query Builder). Please check and let me know is it working or not.

```
DB::table(DB::raw("merchantlink m, company c, merchantlinkrelation mlr"))
->select("c.*")
->whereRaw ("(m.initiator_user_id = c.owner_user_id and m.responder_user_id = 86 and mlr.ptype = 'dealer')")
->orWhereRaw("(m.initiator_user_id = 86 and m.responder_user_id = c.owner_user_id and mlr.ptype = 'dealer')")
->orWhereRaw("(m.initiator_user_id = c.owner_user_id and c.owner_user_id = 86 and mlr.ptype = 'dealer')")
->groupBy("c.id")
->get();
```

Comment: no this is not help ful it gives me error

Comment: can you please tell me what is an error?

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'ocosystemdb.merchantlink m, company c, merchantlinkrelation mlr' doesn't exist (SQL: select `c`.* from `merchantlink m, company c, merchantlinkrelation mlr` where (m.initiator_user_id = c.owner_user_id and m.responder_user_id = 86 and mlr.ptype = 'dealer') is null or (m.initiator_user_id = 86 and m.responder_user_id = c.owner_user_id and mlr.ptype = 'dealer') is null or (m.initiator_user_id = c.owner_user_id and c.owner_user_id = 86 and mlr.ptype = 'dealer') is null group by `c`.`id`)

Comment: @hamza-qureshi I have changed the query. can you please check it?

Answer (score 1):

You could simply do this:

```
DB::Select(
  DB::Raw('
    SELECT
      c.*
    FROM
      merchantlink m,
      company c,
      merchantlinkrelation mlr
    WHERE
       (m.initiator_user_id = c.owner_user_id AND
       m.responder_user_id = 86 AND
       mlr.ptype='dealer')
    OR
       (m.initiator_user_id = 86 AND
       m.responder_user_id = c.owner_user_id AND
       mlr.ptype = 'dealer')
    OR
       (m.initiator_user_id = c.owner_user_id AND
       c.owner_user_id=86 AND
       mlr.ptype='dealer')
    GROUP BY
       c.id
  ')
);
```

But there are probably better ways to do it.